# Grub and multi drive boots

Tags: hard-drive, debian, ssd, grub, kali-linux

I have encountered an issue while setting up a new SSD. Before incorporating the new drive, I had a partitioned HDD, Windows 7 (manufacturer installed) on one partition, with Debian on the other partition. Grub was installed on this hard drive, and upon boot I would filter through the list of bootable OSs and choose what I wanted, Debian or Windows.

Now with a new SSD, I installed Kali on it for fun and when asked about installing Grub, I hit some issues:

If I install Grub on the original HDD, then I am no longer able to find my Debian partition as a boot option. Both the Windows side of the HDD and Kali on the SSD work, but Debian is not listed.

If I install Grub on the new SSD itself, then the original HDD is no longer able to be found when booting, and when it boots the SSD as a result, I just get the blinking cursor and have no options.

I am new to this and trying very hard to solve my own problems. I am not worried particularly about loss of crucial data, and I of course do not need all these distros by any means, I am simply trying to have fun trying different things, but this has presented quite the issue.

If there is any more information I can provide please let me know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using **Boot-Repair**, a tool which fixes this kind of problems.

If you still have access to Debian, boot in and run this in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

This will add the required PPA to your sources, and will also install and run Boot-Repair.

Once it's open, just click *"Recommended repair"* and cross your fingers!

If you need any further information about this, you can take a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Also, let me recommend you to use **virtual machines** for this kind of experiments (testing new distros, messing up with them...), because if you break anything, it won't affect your main system. A very good, and free program for that is [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).